# VS2010 foreach doesn't appear to be working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

This one is strange. Basically, I have a foreach loop: foreach (ApSupplier apSupplierImport in apSuppliers). apSuppliers is a list of ApSupplier objects and ALWAYS contains x number of objects of the ApSupplier class.

I was able to view each apSupplierImport as I stepped through the loop until around noon yesterday. I made a change to the code within the loop (but not to the foreach).

Now, when I hover over the apSupplierImport variable, it shows as null. It appears that it isn't being loaded during the foreach. I believe that there is something in there because the code doesn't error out in the subsequent if I run the original code (though it does when I run the new stuff, which is why I want to see the variable; to figure out what's missing).  It's playing hell with debugging, though I'm unsure as to why because I can't see if there is actually something in the variable.

Image showing there are apSuppliers in the list...
[image: Image showing there are apSuppliers in the list...]

Image showing that apSupplierImport variable (of ApSupplier object) is null after iterating...
[image: Image showing that apSupplierImport variable (of ApSupplier object) is null after iterating...]

Any idea what's going on? Is there some setting I'm missing or that may have changed that's causing variables to NOT display? I haven't been able to get it to work after restarting VS2010, rebuilding or a complete reboot. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Here is the complete foreach loop:

```
                foreach (ApSupplier apSupplierImport in apSuppliers)
            {
                ApSupplier apSupplier = apProperty.ApSuppliers.Where(s => s.Key == apSupplierImport.Key && s.Property.Id == property.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (apSupplier == null)
                {  /*Add new*/
                    apSupplierImport.ApProperty = apProperty;
                    apSupplierImport.Property = property;
                    workspace.Add(apSupplierImport);
                }
                else /*Update*/
                {
                    apSupplier.Name = apSupplierImport.Name;
                    apSupplier.Address = apSupplierImport.Address;
                    apSupplier.Address2 = apSupplierImport.Address2;
                    apSupplier.City = apSupplierImport.City;
                    apSupplier.State = apSupplierImport.State;
                    apSupplier.Zip = apSupplierImport.Zip;
                    apSupplier.PhoneNumber = apSupplierImport.PhoneNumber;
                    apSupplier.Property = property;
                    workspace.Update(apSupplier);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you modifying the apSupplies variable in the foreach loop somewhere? Can you post the full code - your screenshot is cutting off the bottom part of the foreach loop.

Comment: The highlighted brace suggests that you haven't actually entered the loop, have you tried doing a step? Also, your code would be helpful ;o

Comment: try `foreach (ApSuplier apSupplierImport in apSuppliers.ToList())` just add the `.ToList()` extension

Comment: Have you compiled the code in debug mode? If you debug release code you may see effects at least similar to this.

Comment: #Guthwulf, I've included the loop code as you requested.
#Guffa, I am compiling in debug mode... that's why this is so confusing as to why it's happening.